# MVC4 Web Api doesn't serialize my class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've developed a very simple WebApi in order to test some Knockout.js features. IMO it should work properly, but when I make a GET request to the Api via Fiddler, it doesn't return any JSON at all.

I'm using MVC4's JSON default serializer.

This is my model...

```
public class Page
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Control> Controls { get; set; }        
}

public abstract class Control
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract string SayHi();
}

public class Form : Control
{
    public override string SayHi()
    {
        return string.Format("Hi, I'm form {0}", Name);
    }
}

public class Datagrid : Control
{
    public override string SayHi()
    {
        return string.Format("Hi, I'm datagrid {0}", Name);
    }
}
```

...here is my Controller...

```
public class PageController : ApiController
{
    static readonly ISimplePageRepository _repository = new TestPageRepository();

    // GET /api/page
    public IEnumerable<Page> GetAllPages()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

...and just in case, this is my repo...

```
public class TestPageRepository : ISimplePageRepository
{
    private List<Page> _pages = new List<Page>();

    public TestPageRepository()
    {
        Add(new Page {Name = "pagina1", Controls = new List<Control>() {new Datagrid() {Name = "laTablita"}}});
        Add(new Page {Name = "pagina2", Controls = new List<Control>() {new Form() {Name = "elFormito"}}});
    }

    public Page Add(Page item)
    {
        _pages.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Page> GetAll()
    {
        return _pages.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your Page class decorated with a Serializable attribute?

Comment: Already tried, but didn't work... also tried with the other classes but it didn't do the trick

Comment: If I change Page's Controls type to be a List<Form>, it works. Could be some problem with the abstract class?

Comment: A list of an abstract type may present a problem as the objects within that collection cannot be instantiated as that type, but shouldn't have a problem being instantiated as a subtype. Perhaps try refactoring that Page class to use a generic IEnumerable rather than a List of abstract types.

Comment: Nope, it still returns:

e
[{"Controls":[
ebe

Comment: I changed the default serializer to JSON.NET and it worked. Apparently, the problem was with the default serializer and the abstract Control class

Comment: Weird, glad you found a solution though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the default serializer to JSON.NET and it worked. Apparently, the problem was with the default serializer and the abstract Control class.